# lsmon utility in QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

i am using 'lsmon.exe' utility to know the list of users using QTP concurrent license. I execute the lsmon utility and get information in command prompt interface. i am trying to write a excel vba program to display the details in user interface. Is ter any way to get the details displayed in my own user interface, means by executing the command and getting the necessay information.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the command and redirect the output to a text file, then you can load the text file in VBA and parse the information you need to put in your spreadsheet.  Example:

```
lsmon > C:\temp\output.txt
```